# Bash: read values from a file after markers

Tags: bash, scripts, files

I have a file that looks something like this:

```
Variable1 { value1 }
Variable2 { value2 }
...
```

Is there a way to write a script that at least retrieves the values between "{}"?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this purpose with many tools like:

**grep**

```
grep -oP '(?<={ ).*(?= })' FILENAME
```

**awk**

```
awk -F '({ | })' '{print $2}' FILENAME
```

**sed**

```
sed 's/.*{ \(.*\) }/\1/' FILENAME
```

All of above commands have an output like this:

```
value1
value2
```

---

Also you can save these commands output to another file by redirecting or with `tee` command.

For example:

```
grep -oP '(?<={ ).*(?= })' FILENAME > OUTPUT
```

Or:

```
grep -oP '(?<={ ).*(?= })' FILENAME | tee OUTPUT
```